# How to make Firefox open all links in private tabs except those whitelisted?

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions

In the last Firefox versions the possibility to open private tabs was introduced. Is there some way to open any link by default in a private tab except links from a whitelist?

My goal is to prevent untrusted sites from reading my cookies and remove anything left after this site's private tab is closed if I accidentally accepted some cookies from it (by default all cookies are rejected, unfortunately some sites do not work without enabling cookies).

Browsing history doesn't matter, as I don't use it anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two options that I know of:

1. Use an add-on like [Private Tab](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/private-tab/?src=api). While this doesn't use a whitelist it does make it a lot easier to open links in new private tabs (there is an "Open in new Private tab" option from the pop-up menu) or even switch a current tab to private mode.

   [image: tab]
2. Customize the privacy settings in Firefox. You can enable Private browsing mode all the time and you can configure which sites you want to accept cookies from. Simply go to the Options dialog and then to the Privacy tab:

   [image]

   To configure the cookie list click on the Exceptions button:

   [image]