# How to make Firefox open all links in a private window by default?

Tags: firefox, privacy, cookies

How to make Firefox open all links in a private window by default? (I mean, unless I manually chose to open a link in "normal" mode, or it's a link from a site to itself, it should open it in a private window).

It's annoying when I accidentally open some unknown and/or garbage website in "normal" mode and have to clean up all the crap it has left in cookies, cache, etc… But it's important to keep data of some sites between relaunches, so, for example, I won't have to log in to StackOverflow every time.

Using some hidden settings and/or extensions to solve this problem is OK.

I've found a [similar question](https://superuser.com/q/596706/161593), but its accepted answer is not good enough for me, as it requires setting up whitelist for cookies, and it's not clear what will happen with other kinds of data that websites can leave.

Comment: Does this help? `browser.privatebrowsing.autostart = true` in `about:config`.
I know it's just the default mode, but I set up chrome like this and it really helps me a lot.

Comment: Hopefully any solution to this answer will also answer how to open external links in a new private window, though it seems like they could add a new value to the possible values in [`browser.link.open_newwindow.override.external`](https://superuser.com/a/639403/45163).

Comment: Yeah external links are the toughest "enemy". They sometimes cannot even be copied and the only 2 choices are re-type them by hand or click (thereby opening as usual), well, there's also a 3rd option — screenshot and use something like tesseract, but it's not 100% reliable

Answer (score 0):

Like Lenniey suggested:

- `about:config`
- `browser.privatebrowsing.autostart`
- Set as `true`

**Source:** [Firefox - Use Private Browsing as default browsing mode](http://ccm.net/faq/15012-firefox-use-private-browsing-as-default-browsing-mode)

Comment: This does not work for links in a tab — they are opening as usual

Comment: Hmmm, no, I got it — it just makes private browsing the _only_ mode of operation. Clearly it's not what was asked :(

Comment: Even though this solution isn't going to do the trick (need to be able to open cookie windows optionally), still thanks for mentioning this...